# Как автоматизировать конвертер + добавление субтитров в ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

в данный момент мне нужно переконвертировать 220 видео из mkv в mp4 и чтобы не печатать каждый раз, сделал такой код: `for %a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%a" -qscale 0 -vf scale=1920:1080 "%~na.mp4"` , но не понимаю как добавить переменную для субтитров у которых такое же название, как и у видео.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, это вопрос не столько про ffmpeg, сколько про используемую вами командную оболочку

Comment: @andreymal разве нельзя через какие-нибудь переменные это сделать?